# Calculating minutes difference

Tags: mysql, datediff

I'm trying to find users that opened their email that they got during 10 minutes from where a user got the email, however, for me it shows every user, not just users   that opened their email that they got 10 minutes from where a user got an email.

Code that I tried to use

```
SELECT s.id_user as "users opened emails during 10 minutes" FROM emails_clicks as c
JOIN  emails_sent as s
WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, s.date_sent, c.date_click) < 10
GROUP BY s.id_user
```

Data:

```
`emails_sent` - table of sent emails:
a. `id` - a unique id of the sent letter
b. `id_user` - the user to whom the letter was sent. (FK) -> `users`.`id`
c. `id_type` - email type
d. `date_sent` - date and time of sending the letter




`emails_clicks` - table of clicks on emails:
a. `id` - a unique id click on the letter
b. `id_email` is not a unique click email id . (Foreign Key) -> `emails_sent`.`id`
c. `date_click` - date and time of the click on the letter
```

Comment: Your join is not actually joining your tables.  There is no relationship there.  If it was me, I would use JOIN emails_sent s on c.id_email = s.id (if I understand your naming convention correctly...

Answer (score 0):

Your join is not actually joining your tables. There is no relationship there. If it was me, I would use

```
SELECT c.id, s.is_user "users opened emails during 10 minutes"
FROM email_clicks c
JOIN emails_sent s on c.id_email = s.id
WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, s.date_sent, c.date_click) < 10
GROUP BY c.id
```

(if I understand your naming convention correctly...